# react material reset form value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using react material with hooks, I want to perform a reset on material form.

I have been trying to set the state but no changes are reflecting

```
<form className="create-account-form" autoComplete="off" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
  <FormControl
    error={!!errorText.first_name}
    variant="outlined"
    size="small"
    fullWidth
  >
    <InputLabel>First Name</InputLabel>
    <OutlinedInput
      name="first_name"
      className="create-account-input"
      labelWidth={90}
      disabled={loading}
      onChange={event => handleChange("first_name", event)}
    />
  </FormControl>
  <Button
    type="submit"
    className="submit-button"
    color="primary"
    variant="contained"
  >
    Submit
  </Button>
</form>;
//my state varibles

const [signUpData, setSignUpData] = useState({
  first_name: ""
});
const handleChange = (field, event) => {
  if (event) {
    setSignUpData({
      ...signUpData,
      [field]: event.target ? event.target.value : event
    });
  }
};
```

on submit I want to clear that data in the input field.

```
const onSubmit = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
   setSignUpData((prev) => (prev.first_name = "",));

  // clearfunction()
};
```

Answer (score 1):

## Load initial state

```
const init = {first_name: ''};
const [signUpData, setSignUpData] = useState(init)

const onSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  // do submit logic
  setSignUpData(init)
}
```

Comment: I have been setting the state to empty also but no change is reflecting

Answer (score 0):

make an object to reset or initial value set 
as

```
const initial_value={

first_name:""}
```

then `setSignUpData(...initial_value);`becouse you have one input  used this shape
or `setSignUpData(initial_value);`

Answer (score 0):

You see, you haven't actually bind the **state variable** to the **Input field**.

```
<OutlinedInput
      name="first_name"
      className="create-account-input"
      labelWidth={90}
      disabled={loading}
      onChange={event => handleChange("first_name", event)}

      //add this
      value={signUpData.first_name}

    />
```